# How set permission for specific app in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings, django-permissions

I have two REST application in my Django project:

1. ***`api`***  - should be `AllowAny` and `ReadOnly`!
2. ***`apicrm`***  - should be `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated`

How to set this permission for whole app in Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Make local confi like:

api

```
class apiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet) .... {
  permission_classes = ()
  authentication_classes = ()
}
```

apicrm

```
class apiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet) .... {
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated)
  authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean make it for every ViewSet in applications ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any global settings to define permissions for apps.
What I can think here is to make a base view class with the appropriate permissions classes.

**Example**:

`api` app

```
class BaseApiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

# inherit BaseApiViewSet in all other viewsets
class ViewSet1(BaseApiViewSet):
    # code as it is
```

`apicrm` app

```
class BaseApiCrmViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

# similary, inherit from BaseApiCrmViewSet in all other viewsets
```